# Angular material datepicker arrow color

Tags: angular-material, datepicker

In the material datepicker there is a small arrow for changing the year, I managed to change every component's color in the calendar but not this arrow.

[image: Calendar arrow]

I inspected it in the browser and found a `mat-calendar-arrow` class but I can only change the background-color of it and not the arrow's color. Is there a possible way to change it to white? I need it for my dark-theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
.mat-calendar-arrow {
    border-top-color: white;
}
```

Comment: wow.. I don't get the logic in this one but it works so thanks!

Comment: @Kerk no problem. The arrow is created using a little trick with css borders: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle

Comment: ooh that makes sense now